# How do slice and slice! affect the object_id in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am studying `object_id` method behavior in Ruby in order to know when a new object is created. I can understand (1) is identical to (2) and (3) is identical to (4). But I do not understand why (5) is not identical to (6).

*(1) upto (6) are described below with my source code.*

So I would like to understand when `object_id` will be changed (newly assigned) in Ruby. Does anybody explain it concisely?

Thank you very much in advance.

**source code**

```
a = "foo"
b = a
b.slice!(0)

p a.object_id # (1)
p b.object_id # (2)

b = b

p a.object_id # (3)
p b.object_id # (4)

b = b.slice(0)

p a.object_id # (5)
p b.object_id # (6)
```

**result**

```
70302398954840                                                                                                                                                                                      
70302398954840
70302398954840
70302398954840
70302398954840
70302398954680
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not objects and mutating an object does not change *what* the object is. That is, mutating an object will never change which variables evaluate to that object.

The difference between the two methods is that `slice!` mutates the original string/object (ick!) and `slice` returns a new string/object *without* mutating the original (yay!).

In the following `X` denotes a particular (but arbitrary) string, and `Y` represents a *different* particular (but arbitrary) string. Do not confuse `X` and `Y` with variables; they merely represent different objects to explain the behavior.

```
a = X                # a = X
b = a                # b = a -> b = X, so b = X
b.slice!(0)          # MUTATE object X

p a.object_id # (1)  # a = X
p b.object_id # (2)  # b = X

b = b                # b = b -> b = X, so b = X (no effect)

p a.object_id # (3)  # a = X
p b.object_id # (4)  # b = X

b = b.slice(0)       # b = f(b), where NEW object (Y) is returned, so b = Y

p a.object_id # (5)  # a = X
p b.object_id # (6)  # b = Y
```